# JRE Automatic Installation not choosing 64bit?

Tags: nsis, java

I am creating a NSIS installer for a desktop application.
I am making use of [this great sample](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Java_Runtime_Environment_Dynamic_Installer) (JREDyna_Inetc.nsh) to detect if the host already has a JRE of at least v1.6, and if not, the installer goes off and runs a web-installer to get a JRE and install it before proceeding.

This is a 64bit specific installer (earlier step checks for this and aborts if its a 32bit machine).

The detection works fine, but it appears to download a 32bit JRE.

The URL for the web installer is defined as:

```
!define JRE_URL "http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=52252"
```

**Is it the URL that I need to change or perhaps there is an issue with this separate plugin that I am using?**

Comment: Since you specify the bundle to download I suspect its only going to down load that bundle.

Comment: any idea on where to get list of Bundle URLs for JRE so I can pick the right one.  I cannot seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go here - http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

In chrome, hover over links and it gives you the BundleID in the bottom right.
For me at the time of writing this URL works:

http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=60338